# Is there an R function in R shiny to plot stem and display summary table

Tags: r

I am confused with the input and output functions in R Shiny. I need to plot stem function and display summary table for faithful dataset based on input under select input. But the below is not fetching the result i needed. Please advise

```
 library(shiny)

 ui <- fluidPage(
 sidebarLayout(
 sidebarPanel(selectInput("x","Operations",choices = c("summary","stem")),
             plotOutput("x")),
 mainPanel(h6("Here it is"),
          tableOutput("message")
 )
 )
 )

 server <- function(input, output, session) {

 output$message <- renderPlot({
 faithful
 })
 output$x <- reactive({
 if(input$x == "summary")
  {
  summary(faithful$eruptions)
 } 
 else if (input$x == "stem")
  {
  stem(faithful$eruptions)
 }
 )
 })
 }

 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Shiny so below is just my experience. First I think you shall put your `if` condition for the `message` output. Secondly, use the `renderPrint` to render the summary outputs.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(selectInput("x","Operations",choices = c("summary","stem")),
                     uiOutput("x")),
        mainPanel(h6("Here it is"),
                  verbatimTextOutput("message")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #  output$message <- renderUI({
   #     faithful
  #  })
    output$message <- renderPrint({
        if(input$x == "summary")
        {
            summary(faithful$eruptions)
        } else if (input$x == "stem")
        {
            print(stem(faithful$eruptions))
        }
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect thanks. SUppose if need to plot the histogram of eruption, i used plot(hist(faithful$eruptions). But the output is not coming

Comment: Then, you will need `plotOutput` in `ui` and `renderPlot` in `server`.

Comment: I tried (code edited). But still the output is not coming

Comment: Thanks. But if I need a search button under "Operation" so that i can search if there is a long list. How do i? I tried with SelectizeInput but not getting